# Troubles of installing and using Cytoscape

Tags: installation, cytoscape

I have trouble installing Cytoscape 3_8_2. I think it started not having the correct version of Java. Then I installed Java 11. However, I still haven't resolved the issue. When I open Cytoscape, I can not upload any network table (excel and txt format). Besides being unable to import files, I can't do anything in the app. Then I downloaded "System Checker Script" for debugging, "Windows.bat" that yielded the following results :

'jvmVariant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

### Cytoscape System Requirements Checker for Windows

Target Cytoscape version: 3.8.0

Your Windows version is:

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1110]

Java is installed

Your system is 64 bit

JAVA_HOME is not set

Your Java Major version is 11
Your Java version is at least version 11 as required

Your Java version is no higher than version 11 as required

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Problem: The "app" store at apps.cytoscape.org is not reachable

### Summary

Your system has some issues.
Please fix those and re-run this script again:

- App store at apps.cytoscape.org is not reachable

### More details on Java

openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10, mixed mode)

### More details on apps.cytoscape.org

Going to run trace route command for apps.cytoscape.org with timeout of 30000ms now...

Tracing route to apps.cytoscape.org [52.34.133.210]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

1     4 ms     4 ms     3 ms  10.185.180.1
2     4 ms     2 ms     3 ms  host-31-29.ilurtow.clients.pavlovmedia.com [216.171.31.29]
3     5 ms     4 ms     5 ms  host-30-2.ilurtow.clients.pavlovmedia.com [216.171.30.2]
4     7 ms     6 ms     5 ms  te0-3-1-19.nr51.b021117-0.ind01.atlas.cogentco.com [38.140.177.185]
5     4 ms     5 ms     4 ms  be2222.rcr21.ind01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.24.66.117]
6    12 ms    11 ms    13 ms  be3180.ccr41.ord01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.45.170]
7    22 ms    23 ms    23 ms  be2831.ccr21.mci01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.42.165]
8    34 ms    35 ms    34 ms  be3035.ccr21.den01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.5.89]
9    45 ms    45 ms    46 ms  be3037.ccr21.slc01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.41.145]
10    60 ms    60 ms    60 ms  be3109.ccr21.sfo01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.44.137]
11    62 ms    61 ms    61 ms  be3669.ccr41.sjc03.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.43.10]
12    64 ms    71 ms    70 ms  38.88.224.186
13    68 ms     *       67 ms  52.93.70.184
14    64 ms    71 ms    65 ms  150.222.97.89
15    77 ms    76 ms    78 ms  150.222.97.104
16    78 ms    76 ms    77 ms  52.93.133.80
17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
21     *        *        *     Request timed out.

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What that is telling you is that you are not able to get to the app store.  That should not prevent you from installing and running Cytoscape, but you will need to figure out the networking issues before installing any apps.

-- scooter